# Push-out of two cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, modules, abelian-groups

Given module morphisms $\alpha:C\rightarrow A$ and $\beta:C\rightarrow B$, their push-out is *constructed* as follows.

Let $K$ be the submodule of $A\oplus B$ given by $\{(\alpha(c), -\beta(c))\,\,|\,\, c\in C\}$.

Then the module in the pushout of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $(A\oplus B)/K$;

the morphisms from $A$ and from $B$ to $(A+B)/K$ are obtained by composition of inclusion of each one into $A\oplus B$ and then canonical projection onto $(A\oplus B)/K$.

My question is elementary: we are quotienting the direct sum of $A$ and $B$ by elements $(\alpha(c),-\beta(c))$, which can be written as
$$
(\alpha(c),0) - (0,\beta(c)).
$$
In other words, quotienting $A\oplus B$ by submodule of these elements is, roughly equivalent to say that

> *identify images in $A\oplus B$ under $\alpha$ and images in $A\oplus B$ under $\beta$ of same element $c$*?

**Question 1.** Is this right way of thinking pushout? If this is correct, then, psuhout of
$$\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4,\,\,\,  x\mapsto x\pmod{4} \hskip5mm \mbox{ and } \hskip5mm 
\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6,\,\,\,  y\mapsto y\pmod{6}
$$
will be
$$
\langle x,y\,\,|\,\, x^4=1, \,\, y^6=1, \,\, xy=yx, \,\, x=y\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2.
$$
**Question 2.** Is this correct?

Comment: Assuming you're working in the category of abelian groups; 1. yes, 2. yes.